# How to rotate a single shape in 3d space in opengl?

Tags: java, opengl, rotation, shapes

so I'm pretty new with opengl and creating 3d shapes. So for my example I have two squares, one with a height/width 2 with the center at the origin coordinate (0,0,-10), and one that is to the far left side of the window. I am trying to rotate the square that lies in the origin along the x-z plane without rotating the square that is located to the far left side of the screen. My approach to this was to save each xyz coordinate of the center square to a variable, and creating a method that uses the behavior of cos(theta) to rotate the square along the x-z plane. My code works, but I assume this is a horrible approach as there must be some more efficient method that is already created that can do the same functionality. I looked at glRotatef(), but from what I understood this only rotates my camera view which in the end would rotate both the middle square and the far left square whereas I only want to rotate the middle square. Is there some other method that already exists that can easily rotate a single 2d shape in 3d space?

In case its relevant, I have included the rotating code I made myself for the middle square: (btw the blue class is just some class I made that has the squares coordinates and the circle degree for cos(theta))

```
if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)) {

            blue.setCircle(blue.getCircle()+1f);//getCircle is initially zero and gets incremented by 1 for everytime the program loops with the user holding the left button.

            blue.setXfrontTR((float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(blue.getCircle())));//Changing top-right x coordinate of the middle square
            blue.setZfrontTR(-10f+ ((float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(blue.getCircle()+270f)))); //Changing top-right z coordinate of the middle square.

            blue.setXfrontTL((float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(blue.getCircle()+180f)));
            blue.setZfrontTL(-10f+ ((float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(blue.getCircle()+90f))));//Changing top-left x,z coordinates

            blue.setXfrontBL((float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(blue.getCircle()+180f)));
            blue.setZfrontBL(-10f+ ((float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(blue.getCircle()+90f))));//Changing bottom-left x,z coordinates

            blue.setXfrontBR((float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(blue.getCircle())));
            blue.setZfrontBR(-10f+ ((float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(blue.getCircle()+270f))));//Changing bottom-right x-z coordinates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give each object that requires independent movement a model-view matrix you can achieve this. The other option to quickly draw/move a few independent objects is to:

for each object:

pushMatrix()

draw object

popMatrix()

while in the modelview matrix...

The method of drawing depends greatly on the OpenGL version you're coding to but the above will work for simple drawing. I'm not an expert on OpenGL / 3D programming so, if you wait a bit you may hear(see) better wisdom than what I offer :)